# ng-pattern to validate last letter must end with a specific letter angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I am trying to ensure that the last letter of a field must end with a specific letter in angularjs text field. I have created a function that handles the pattern validation as shown

```
$scope.validatePattern = function () {
    var typeSelected = $scope.sports_type;
    if (typeSelected == 'Sports') { //the user selected sports from the above model
        $scope.pointPattern = "^[\s\w]+[^(ess|essence)]$";
    }
}
```

I am using the pattern in below fields.

```
<label>Sports Option</label>
<input ng-model="option" ng-minlength="3" formcontrol name="option" type="text" ng-pattern="{{pointPattern}}" required>
<p ng-show="frmValidation.option.$invalid" class="input-error-message">Option is required</p>
<p ng-show="frmValidation.option.$error.pattern">Not valid! Must end with ess or essence</p>
```

why is the ng-pattern not validating that the letter must end with ess or essence

Comment: You probably can use `"^(?!.*ess(?:ence)?$)"` or `"^(?!.*ess(?:ence)?$).*"`

Comment: I used this >>> ^(?!.*ess(?:ence)?$) I added a sentence eg football ess and it was not validated as a correct pattern

Comment: You need the `.*` with a string pattern, or use `$scope.pointPattern = /^(?!.*ess(?:ence)?$)/;`

Comment: the idea is for it to end with ess or essence but with the above regex, reverse is the case. Its not allowing the textfiled to end with ess or essence

Comment: Oh, then yes, just `$scope.pointPattern = /ess(?:ence)?$/;` will work. Why did you try to negate it?

Comment: working now, what about if I want to allow more letters e.g /ess(?:ence)(?:sports)?$/ will this work

Comment: You would use `/(?:ess(?:ence)?|sports)$/` to match strings ending with `ess`, `essence` or `sports`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match strings ending with `ess`, `essence` or `sports` you may use

```
$scope.pointPattern = /(?:ess(?:ence)?|sports)$/;
```

Note that you must use a `RegExp` variable type.  It is equal to `$scope.pointPattern = new RegExp("(?:ess(?:ence)?|sports)$");` and it is required if you plan to match a substring in your input string.

If you plan to use a string pattern, you will need to make sure it matches the whole input string:

```
$scope.pointPattern = "^.*(?:ess(?:ence)?|sports)$";
```

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `(?:ess(?:ence)?|sports)` - a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) matching

  - `ess(?:ence)?` - `ess` followed with an optional `ence` substring
  - `|` - or
  - `sports` - a `sports` substring
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: when I end with ence, its not validating here is it >>> $scope.pointPattern = /(?:ess(?:ence)?|sports)$/;

Comment: If you want to fail the strings ending with `ence` you need `$scope.pointPattern = /(?:ess|ence|sports)$/;` - simple. You may actually tweak the pattern further based on my pattern explanation. E.g. `?` makes a pattern optional, `(?:...)?` makes a sequence optional. `sports?` will match `sport` and `sports`.

Comment: I have a quick observation do not know if you close by

Comment: if I do this goess. It will get validated but it is not supposed to be valid either. It should only be valid when it ends with ess separated by a space

Comment: Do you mean it should be matched as a whole word? `/\b(?:ess|ence|sports)$/`? If you really mean a whitespace: `/(?:^|\s)(?:ess|ence|sports)$/`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `[^(ess|essence)]` is a negated character class that will match one character that is not one of (,e,s,|,n,c or ), also you are looking at the end of the string so you can drop the `^[\s\w]+` part.

I'm assuming that the regex matches valid input so you need to rewrite it as

```
$scope.pointPattern = "ess(?:ence)?$";
```

This matches `ess` possibly followed by `ence` followed by the end of the string.